# VirtualBox has stopped working due to Qt4 lib

Tags: qt, dll, qt4, virtualbox, windows-7-x64

I builded VirtualBox for win7 64 bit, i start VirtualBox.exe, it's working fine but when I try to create a new virtual machine or I navigate inside menus I get this error:

> Problem signature:
>     Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
>     Application Name: VirtualBox.exe
>     Application Version:  1.0.0.0
>     Application Timestamp:    52cd8ef9
>     Fault Module Name:    QtGui4.dll
>     Fault Module Version: 4.8.5.0
>     Fault Module Timestamp:   52c58365
>     Exception Code:   c0000005
>     Exception Offset: 000000000046af2f
>     OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
>     Locale ID:    1033
>     Additional Information 1: ef6f
>     Additional Information 2: ef6f9ba7d825b93e78ca15b3aa28f7a5
>     Additional Information 3: fd9f
>     Additional Information 4: fd9ffe4701a0e9c909f7145c40abacf9

Do anybody has any idea what seems to be the problem? The program closes after this error.
Thank you

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming related question.

Comment: Unless you debuged the crash and have found a problem with Qt, I would assume that it is a bug in VirtualBox, so report a bug there.